# Check if values in a range are equal to values in an user defined type

Tags: excel, vba

Assume that I have an user defined type:

```
Public Type myType
    slot1 As Integer
    slot2 As String
End Type
```

In my code I assign values to that type (in reality via an userform):

```
Sub test()
   Dim mT As myType
   mT.slot1 = 1
   mT.slot2 = "test"
End Sub
```

What I want now is to loop through the rows of a table and check whether the first `n` columns of any row coincide with the `n` slots in `mT` (`n = 2`in this particular case):

```
Function IsMember(mT as myType, rngIN as Range) As Boolean
   Dim i As Long
   IsMember = False
   For i = 1 To rngIN.Rows.Count
      IsMember = rngIN.Cells(i, 1) = mT.slot1 And rngIN.Cells(i, 2) = mT.slot2
      If (IsMember) Then
         Exit For
      End If
   Next i
End Function
```

Since I have a lot of slots in my user defined type, I was wondering whether there is a smarter way to do this comparison rather then hard-coding comparisons for all slots? Something like looping through the type? Or maybe another data structure would be better to do this comparison efficiently?

Comment: I don't think you can iterate a type. How about a variant array instead?

Comment: The reason I have chosen the `type`is that in my function I can guarantee that I have the right arguments and I need to do the checking hence only once in all my functions. So is there any way to combine the goodies of a type with the iteration possibility of an array?

Comment: Maybe pair an array with an enum? myArray(myEnum.Slot1)